# Complex numbers and polynomial solutions

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Let $z = a + ib$ be a complex number. Find real numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $z$ is a solution of $$ z^2 +pz +q = 0$$ Find all complex numbers $w$ such that $w$ and $i$ are solutions of a polynomial $z^2 + pz + q$ with $p$ and $q$ real.

For the first part, I have no idea how you can "eliminate" $z$ when $p$ and $q$ must be real numbers.

Comment: "Eliminating the $z$" is done [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Derivation_of_the_formula). But in those problems what they are testing is that you know that if a complex number is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients, then the conjugate of the number is also a root. Therefore, if $a+ib$ is a root, so is $a-ib$. You can conclude that the polynomial is the same as $(z-a-ib)(z-a+ib)=z^2-2az+a^2+b^2$. For the second problem the conjugate of $i$ is forced to also be a root.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2602473/491874, which just came through a few hours ago. You're not the only person who is doing this homework assignment with the help of Math.SE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex Polynomial, Input That Also Is A Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602473/complex-polynomial-input-that-also-is-a-solution)

Answer (score 1):

If all coefficients of the quadratic are real, and you have $z=a+ib$ as solution, you will also have $\bar{z}=a-ib$ as solution

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the fact that the conjugate is also a root, you can compute the polinomal in terms of $a$ and $b$ and force it to vanish.

$z^2+pz+q= (a^2-b^2+2abi)+(pa+pbi)+q=0$

For a complex number to be $0$ means that the real and the imaginary part are both $0$, so you've got the system of equations

$
\begin{cases}
a^2-b^2+pa+q=0\\
2ab+pb=0
\end{cases}
$

If you solve it for $p$ and $q$ you'll get the answer.